# Update row with data from another row in the same table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, updates

In SQLite database, I've got a table:

```
ID | ParentID | Price
---------------------
1  | null     | -1
2  | 1        | 100
3  | 1        | 200
4  | null     | -1
5  | 4        | 300
6  | 4        | 300
```

How to update parent rows price (ParentID is null) using their child price with the following rules:

- *If all the childs row has the same Price, the parent price will be updated to that price. Otherwise, the parent price will be update to 0.*

The output I'm looking for is:

```
ID | ParentID | Price
---------------------
1  | null     | 0
2  | 1        | 100
3  | 1        | 200
4  | null     | 300
5  | 4        | 300
6  | 4        | 300
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
UPDATE
   MyTable
SET
   Price = (SELECT P.ChildPrice 
            FROM (SELECT ParentID, 
                         (CASE COUNT(DISTINCT Price) 
                          WHEN 1 THEN Price 
                          ELSE 0 END) AS ChildPrice 
                  FROM InventoryItem 
                  WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL 
                  GROUP BY ParentID) P
            WHERE InventoryItem.ID = P.ParentID)
WHERE
   ParentID IS NULL
```